# how to search data from an output table using php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I new to php, ajax and mysql. I am trying to build a web application where i get an output table from my database. My question is what code should i use if i want to search another table using the current output table for eg

name            surname
 john           smith

is my out put table, if i click on smith it should search other table containing data about smith

My js code is

```
$(function myFunction() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
      var value = $('#str').val();
      var value1= $('#str1').val();
       $.post('test_refresh.php',{value:value,value1:value1}, function(data){
         $("#search_results").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
```

My Php code is

```
    <?php
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db("cancer database") or die(mysql_error());
echo"";
/*$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM  tbl_cancer_database
WHERE  gene_symbol LIKE  '".$_POST['value']."'
OR  gene_name LIKE  '".$_POST['value']."'
OR  gene_id LIKE  '".$_POST['value']."'
OR  gene_locus LIKE '".$_POST['value']."'
OR  function LIKE  '%".$_POST['value']."%'
OR  alteration_in_cancer LIKE '".$_POST['value']."'
OR  reference LIKE '".$_POST['value']."'
");*/
$query = mysql_query("SELECT  * FROM  tbl_cancer_database
WHERE  gene_name LIKE  '".$_POST['value']."'
and gene_id LIKE  '".$_POST['value1']."'
");
echo '<br />';

echo "You have searched for ".$_POST['value']." and ".$_POST['value1']."";
echo '<br />';
echo '<br />';
echo '<table>';
echo "<tr>
<th bgcolor=silver>Sr. No.</th> 
<th bgcolor=silver>Gene Symbol</th>
<th bgcolor=silver>Gene Name</th>
<th bgcolor=silver>Gene Id</th> 
<th bgcolor=silver>Gene locus</th> 
<th bgcolor=silver>Function</th> 
<th bgcolor=silver>Alteration in cancer</th> 
<th bgcolor=silver>Reference</th></tr>";


while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

  echo '<tr style="background-color:pink;">
    <td>'.$data["id"].'</td>
    <td>'.$data["gene_symbol"].'</td>
    <td><a href="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov  /gene/?term='.$data["gene_name"].'">'.$data["gene_name"].'</a></td>
    <td>'.$data["gene_id"].'</td>
    <td>'.$data["gene_locus"].'</td>
    <td>'.$data["function"].'</td>
    <td>'.$data["alteration_in_cancer"].'</td>
    <td>'.$data["reference"].'</td>
  </tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: your script looks ok, what problem you are facing now?

Comment: {value:value,value1:value1} change it to {"value":value,"value1":value1}

Comment: @PraDes...this script is working fine i know... my problem is that i dont know how to search from the output i am getting i.e. the table i am getting as an output... how to search a term by clicking on it

Answer (score 0):

First of all add a class that uniquely identifies each of your table data.

So your table would look like this

```
<table>
 <tr>
   <td class="fistname">John</td>
   <td class="lastname">Smith</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Then your javascript would look like this

```
$(function myFunction() {
 $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
  var value = $('#str').val();
  var value1= $('#str1').val();
   $.post('test_refresh.php',{value:value,value1:value1}, function(data){
     $("#search_results").html(data);
     initializeClick();
   });
   return false;
});
});

function initializeClick(){
  $('.firstname').click(function(){
    var sSearchValue = $(this).text();
     $.post('PAGE TO SEARCH YOUR OTHER TABLE',{value:sSearchValue}, function(data){
       //CAN DO WHAT EVER YOU WANT WITH THE RESULTS HERE
     });
   });

}
```

Also keep in mind to escape characters when they are output on the html

Comment: I tried using this code echo'<tr style="background-color:pink;">
    <td class="id">'.$data["id"].'</td>
    <td class="gene_symbol">'.$data["gene_symbol"].'</td>
 <td class="gene_name">'.$data["gene_name"].'</td>
    <td class="gene_id">'.$data["gene_id"].'</td>
    <td class="gene_locus">'.$data["gene_locus"].'</td>
    <td class="function">'.$data["function"].'</td>
    <td class="alteration">'.$data["alteration_in_cancer"].'</td>
    <td class="reference">'.$data["reference"].'</td>
  </tr>';
} and the js code that you gave but I am unable to click on my output html data..

Comment: do i have to insert a hyperlink in the table data so that i can click on it.. sorry if i sound stupid but i am new to this stuff...

Comment: You dont need a hyperlink mate. You can click on it and the javascript will pick it up based on the class.

Comment: Sorry but its not picking up

Comment: Paste your new javascript here.

Comment: $(function initializeClick(){
$(".genename").click(function(){
    var sSearchValue = $(this).text();
     $.post('test_refresh.php',{value:sSearchValue}, function(data){
        $("#search_results").html(data);
     });
   });
   });

Comment: it  seems class is not getting parsed to the js

Comment: when i am using the class of some ather element say header it is working